# Event listener memory leaks in javascript

Tags: javascript, events, dom

I am writing a javascript RIA. I target mainly modern browsers, i.e. latest Firefox, Chrome, IE9+. I heard that old browsers are very easy to introduce memory leaks in, when we create a cycle between DOM nodes and JavaScript objects. Where should I worry about this problem? Is it fixed in more modern browsers? Could you give me some further reading?

Comment: By "old browsers" you mean "old IEs". Don't worry about it, even if there are memory leaks, they are small (even in IE) and I doubt that you'll be affected by them.

Comment: I am actually going to use new GWT elemental, "to the metal", mapping in GWT which wraps browser APIs. The GWT widget library uses tricks to get rid of IE memory leaks, so I want to know whether I have to do the same.

Comment: @freakish I mean not memory leaks in IE, but detail of garbage collection in browsers which might lead to leaks on some browser but not on others.